# How set mysql database creata password with consisting of ==> '

Tags: mysql, sql, cmd, mariadb

I want to make new user with password ==>   d'0g=<<[enU^HXpt

But I get sintax error because 'd' <== this part in password

MYSQL command look like this:

CREATE USER 'student'@'example.com' IDENTIFIED BY 'd'0g=<<[enU^HXpt'

how I can select this password without sintax error?  (d'0g=<<[enU^HXpt)

- summary: How I can make password what include => (') this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type it in as `\'`. This is called escaping and you can read about it here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/string-literals/